# prove $(p → r) ∨ ( q → r)$ logically equivalent to the statement $(p∧q) → r$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I came across this problem, it asks to use logical equivalences (see image), show that $(p → r) ∨ (q → r)$ logically equivalent to the statement $(p ∧ q) → r$ (aka definition of biconditional)

After apply $p→q ≡ ¬p∨q$,  I can't go any further can anyone show me any steps further?

Thank you

[Image logical equivalences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJP4E.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(p → r) ∨ ( q → r)=(¬p ∨ r) ∨ (¬q ∨ r)=¬p ∨ r ∨ ¬q ∨ r=(¬p ∨ ¬q) ∨ r=¬(p∧q)∨r=(p∧q) → r$

Answer (score 0):

Fill in the blanks
$$\begin{align}
 (p\to r)\wedge (q\to r)
\iff & (\neg p\vee r)\wedge (q\to r) & \textsf{Implication Equivalence}
\\[1ex] \iff & (\neg p\vee r)\wedge (\neg q\vee r) &\textsf{Implication Equivalence}
\\[1ex] \iff & ~ & \textsf{Distribution} 
\\[1ex] \iff & ~ & \textsf{Association & Commutation} 
\\[1ex] \iff & ~ & \textsf{De Morgan's Duality} 
\\[1ex] \iff &  (p\vee q)\to r & \textsf{Implication Equivalence}
\end{align}$$